# How to get a response body using Observables

Tags: json, angular, angular-http

I'm using the ng-book as a reference and one of those examples uses observable to get json data but now I want to retrieve data for my own project using a different api which is this http://mindicador.cl/api 
but I got an error which is "Return expression type is not assignable to type Observables". How can I solve this? or How can I get json data with observables?

```
import {
  Injectable,
  Inject
} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Indicadores} from '../indicadores/indicadores.model';

export const MINDICADOR_API = 'http://mindicador.cl/api';

@Injectable()
export class MindicadorService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(MINDICADOR_API) private apiUrl: string) {
  }

  search(): Observable<Indicadores> {
    const queryUrl = this.apiUrl;
    return this.http.get(queryUrl)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        return new Indicadores()
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were try to return from `subscribe`, which tends to return `subscription` object.

It seems like you want to return a data `Observable<Indicadores>` so have `<Indicadores>` is enough after `http.get`

```
search(): Observable<Indicadores> {
    const queryUrl = this.apiUrl;
    return this.http.get<Indicadores>(queryUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the observable from the service as below:

```
search(): Observable<Indicadores> {
const queryUrl = this.apiUrl;
    return this.http.get(queryUrl)
    );
  }
```

And in your controller, use the .subscribe to get the data